# How to interact with a Component's aggregation

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, components, sapui5

I've configured an aggregation for my Component. It looks like this:

```
        aggregations : {
            busyDialog : {
                type: "sap.m.BusyDialog",
                multiple: false
            }
        }
```

So, the aggregation is called "busyDialog" and can contain objects of the type "sap.m.BusyDialog".

I'm also able to get the object with its settings via `my.ui5.namespace.Component.getMetadata().getAggregations().busyDialog`

However, I'm not sure what's the best way to add an item to it or access an already added control in the aggregation. Are there any methods like "addbusyDialog" or something?

Was following this:
http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/01/87ea5e2eff4166b0453b9dcc8fc64f/content.htm?fullscreen=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenUI5 automatically generates the following methods for aggregations where `multiple` is `false` (where `item` is the name of the aggregation):

```
setItem(oItem)
getItem()
destroyItem()
```

And it creates these methods where `multiple` is `true`:

```
addItem(oItem)
insertItem(oItem, iIndex)
getItems()
indexOfItem(oItem)
removeItem(vItem) // item or index of item
removeAllItems()
destroyItems()
```

To answer your specific question, the best way to manipulate your `busyDialog` aggregation is to use these generated methods:

```
myComponent.setBusyDialog(oBusyDialog);
myComponent.getBusyDialog();
myComponent.destroyBusyDialog();
```

Source: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html